# expect script with RSA private key refused with ec2 instance

Tags: shell, amazon-ec2, rsa, sftp, expect

This is an example expect script I found for entering a password for sftp protocol. Right now, I want to copy files from one ec2 instance to another via a script. Later I want to transfer files between a amazon server and another external server using sftp so please don't give me anything amazon specific for solving this issue. The connection is refused when I run this script and I believe it's because I need to give the .pem file with the rsa key, however I don't know how to do this or modify my script to do so. I can't seem to find the answer to this specific issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn sftp ec2-user@mywebsite.com
expect "password:" 
send "[rsa private key]\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "cd \n"
expect "sftp>"
send "put /home/ec2-user/[file]\n"
expect "sftp>"
send "exit\n"
interact
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spawn sftp -i /path/to/pem/file ec2-user@mywebsite.com
```

Not all implemetations of sftp support **-i** option to pass your private key. In that case use:

```
spawn sftp -oIdentityFile=/path/to/pem/file ec2-user@mywebsite.com
```

**-o** can be used to pass options to ssh in the format used in ssh_config.
For more info: `man sftp`

Comment: An explanation of this answer and what the code does would make this a much clearer and much more useful answer.

Comment: No problem at all, just passed it in the review queue and thought i'd mention it. Looks good